# "Ugly" evaluation order in Manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I have this piece of code which plots certain streamlines in a `Manipulate` environment:

```
ph[r_, th_, a_] := r^(Pi/a) Cos[Pi/a th];
g[r_, th_] := {r Cos[th], r Sin[th]} 
pp[a_] := 
 Module[{pl}, 
  pl = StreamPlot[{D[ph[r, th, a], th]/r, -D[ph[r, th, a], r]/r}, {r, 
     0.1, 3}, {th, 0, a}, 
    StreamPoints -> 
     Join[Table[{rs, 0}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, 0.2}], 
      Table[{rs, a}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, 0.2}]], 
    StreamStyle -> {"Line", Darker[Blue]}] ;
  pl[[1, 2, 1]] = g @@@ pl[[1, 2, 1]];
  pl]
Manipulate[
 Show[pp[\[Alpha]], PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], {\[Alpha], Pi/8,
   15 Pi/8}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

The module creates a plot of the streamlines in an r-th plane first, and then transforms the plot into Cartesian coordinates. The code works fine, in principle, but whenever I grab the slider the graphics turns red, and I can see that Manipulate shows the StreamPlot in the r-th plane until I let go of the slider, at which point Manipulate shows the correct plot.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because you use `g@@@`.

Comment: But what's wrong with doing that? What can/should I use instead?

Comment: Nothing specifically wrong with it, but I think it's somehow not running properly when you drag the slider. The error it gives is "g is not a graphics primitive".

Comment: When the control moves, the system changes `$PerformanceGoal = "Speed"`, which causes `StreamPlot` not to produce a `GraphicComplex` based output.  Your use of `pl[[1,2,1]]` assumes the output is of this form. Try setting the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` explicitly in `StreamPlot` and see if it responds adequately quickly.

Comment: Ahah! Yes, setting `PerformanceGoal->Quality` still gives adequate response. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the control moves, the system changes `$PerformanceGoal` to `"Speed"`, which causes `StreamPlot` not to produce a `GraphicComplex` based output. The use of `pl[[1,2,1]]` assumes the output is of this form. One can try setting the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` explicitly in StreamPlot and see if the response time is satisfactory.

```
pp[a_] := 
 Module[{pl}, 
  pl = StreamPlot[{D[ph[r, th, a], th]/r, -D[ph[r, th, a], r]/r},
    {r, 0.1, 3}, {th, 0, a}, 
    StreamPoints -> 
     Join[Table[{rs, 0}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, 0.2}], 
      Table[{rs, a}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, 0.2}]], 
    StreamStyle -> {"Line", Darker[Blue]}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  pl[[1, 2, 1]] = g @@@ pl[[1, 2, 1]];
  pl]
```

If performance is an issue, then using `ReplaceAll` may be more robust.  (To further improve performance, one could use [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html) to speed up dynamic interactivity.)

```
pp[a_] := 
 Module[{pl}, 
  pl = StreamPlot[{D[ph[r, th, a], th]/r, -D[ph[r, th, a], r]/r},
    {r, 0.1, 3}, {th, 0, a},
    StreamPoints -> 
     Join[Table[{rs, 0}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, ControlActive[0.4, 0.2]}], 
      Table[{rs, a}, {rs, 0.1, 3.0, ControlActive[0.4, 0.2]}]],
    StreamStyle -> {"Line", Darker[Blue]}];
  pl /. (h : GraphicsComplex | Arrow)[p_, rest___] :> h[g @@@ p, rest]]
```

If you wish to avoid arrows during active manipulation of the control, change the replacement rule to

```
(h : GraphicsComplex | Arrow | Line)[p_?MatrixQ, rest___] :>
  {Arrowheads[0], h[g @@@ p, rest]}
```